# asp.net mvc viewmodel null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, object-reference

I work on a asp.net mvc project. 
I start to get "object reference" error message. 
My Action method returns viewmodel.

```
return View(GetDetail(Id));
```

When I debug and watch returned model I see that all properties value's are filled.
Nevertheless I get "object reference" error.
I shared a screenshot below. 
Could you please inform me what kind of situations do I live ?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you compile again?

Comment: Delete files from temp asp.net folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: try with `return View(new GetDetail(Id));`

Comment: Since when did calling a method require `new`? @PranavPatel

Comment: @PatrickHofman I created viewmodel in GetDetail method. GetDetail method returns viewmodel (new).

Comment: @PranavPatel ActionResult method returns  "return View(GetDetail(Id));"

Comment: @j.v .I tried to delete temp files but it didnt work for me

Comment: @PatrickHofman I complied again. not changed.

Comment: On your breakpoint...humour me, look at model in the debug window and tell us, do you see the ToUser object with the property populated from their

Comment: Please, show us the `UserInfo` definition